# Problem in PostgreSQL replication - ALTER DATABASE

Tags: postgresql, replication

Recently I put to work a Master/Slave replication in my PostgreSQL (9.3). Everything is ok... insert, update, delete, in data and changes in tables... but when I changed the data base name the replication not works. The name of the Slave database has not changed. How can I configure the master/slave replication to do this (replication of `alter database rename`)?

Comment: Which replication solution are you using? Also: 9.3 is no longer supported, you should plan the upgrade to a supported version as soon as possible.

Comment: Upgrade is not a possibility. the system is third-party and requires PostGreSQL 9.3.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are talking about “streaming replication”, not some other kind of replication (streaming replication is the only kind of replication that I know that replicates DDL).

Streaming replication should replicate `ALTER DATABASE ... RENAME TO ...` just like any other change.

If it doesn't, there is probably some replication conflict that delays the application of the change. What is `max_standby_streaming_delay`set to? try to disconnect from the standby server and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Hi Laurenz,

     In reality I realized that replication was "broken". Something happened that the slave was no longer synchronizing with the master. The error below caught on the slave. I am not using archive on, only replica by streaming.

    <2019-03-19 16: 23: 58,846 -03> LOG: Started WAL Flow of Principal on E / BC000000 at Timeline 1
    <2019-03-19 16: 23: 58,846 -03> FATAL: Could not Receive Data from WAL Flow: ERROR: WAL Required Segment 000000010000000E000000BC Has Been Removed